# Fast inserts; BulkCopy with relational data

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, sqlbulkcopy

I have a large amount of constantly incoming data (roughly 10,000 a minute, and growing) that I want to insert into a database as efficiently as possible. At the moment I'm using prepared insert statements, but am thinking of using the SqlBulkCopy class to import the data in larger chunks.

The problem is that I'm not inserting into a single table - elements of the data item are inserted into numerous tables, and their identity columns are used as foreign keys in other rows that are inserted at the same time. I understand that bulk copies aren't meant to allow for more complex inserts like this, but I wonder if it is worth exchanging my identity columns (bigints in this case) for uniqueidentifier columns. This will allow me to do a couple of bulk copies for each table, and since I can determine the IDs before the insert, I don't need to check for anything like SCOPE_IDENTITY which is preventing me from using bulk copy.

Does this sound like a viable solution, or are there other potential issues I might face? Or, is there another way I can insert data quickly, but retain my use of bigint identity columns?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are planning on exchanging "SQL assigns a [bigint identity() column] surrogate key" with a "data prep routine assings a GUID surrogate key" methodology. In other words, the key will not be assigned within SQL, but from outside SQL. Given your volumes, if the data-generating process *can* assign surrogate key, I'd definitely go with that.

The question then becomes, must you use GUIDs, or can your data-generation process produce auto-incrementing integers? Creating such a process that works consistantly and infallibly is hard (one reason why you pay $$$ for SQL Server), but the trade-off for smaller and more human-legible keys within the database might be worth it.

Comment: "Creating such a process that works consistantly and infallibly is hard . . ." True, but if you're doing it in a single, unshared application outside the database, it's a lot easier. No contention, no race conditions, no transactions.

Comment: I tried the GUID and am getting 10x the performance (approp. 10,000 inserts per second). :)

Answer (score 3):

uniqueidentifier will probably make things worse: page splits and wider. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904405/sql-server-uniqueidentifier-plus-integer-compound-pk-what-type-of-index-to-u)

If your load is/can be batched, one options is to:

- you load a staging table
- load the real tables in one go as a stored procedure
- use a uniqueidentifier in the staging table for each batch

We deal with peaks of around 50k rows per second (and increasing this way). We actually use a separate staging database to avoid double transaction log writes)

Comment: I'm experimenting with a sequential GUID (aka. COMB), generated in C#, which I think ought to get around the clustered index problems from your link. At first glance, I quite liked your staging table idea which I assume is meant to store the rows with GUIDs PKs, and then transfer them to a table with IDENTITY PKs. However, doesn't this still involve having to do a lot of INSERTs since I need to get the identity column? Perhaps I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: @Bargauast: we use the GUID to identify a single batch (some from SQL BulkCopy, other generated by some risk engines). Then we flush into the main tables with bigint clustered keys. The GUID is not the clustered key, merely a way to keep track of batches of data for flushing to the main table. GUID is still 16 bytes wide whether sequential or not and this adds up over billions of rows.